# For what values of $n$ is the complete graph $K_n$ bipartite?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I understand what complete graphs are and what bipartite graphs are. In the bipartite graph, every point from the same set is not connected, but they are connected to every other point of the other set. But my question is, but what values of $n$ in $K_n$ is $K$ bipartite?

I think that the best way to answer this question is $K_{m,n}$ where $m$ are vertices in one partition and $n$ are vertices in another partition. I'm not sure if there is another way to look at this though.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: A bipartite graph cannot contain a triangle.

Comment: So only K1 and K2 are bipartite?